# Greedy and Lazy quantifier. Testing with HTML tags

Tags: html, regex, python-3.x, regex-greedy

Input is

```
<p>
The very <em>first</em> task is to find the beginning of a paragraph.
</p>
<p>
Then you have to find the end of the paragraph
</p>
```

Expected First Output is ( as I am using greedy quantifier)

```
<p>
The very <em>first</em> task is to find the beginning of a paragraph.
</p>
<p>
Then you have to find the end of the paragraph
</p>
```

Code used for Greedy as below

```
text = '''
<p>
The very <em>first</em> task is to find the beginning of a paragraph.
</p>
<p>
Then you have to find the end of the paragraph
</p>
'''
pattern=re.compile(r'\<p\>.*\<\/p\>')
data1=pattern.match(text,re.MULTILINE)
print('data1:- ',data1,'\n')
```

Expected second Output is ( as I am using Lazy quantifier)

```
<p>
The very <em>first</em> task is to find the beginning of a paragraph.
</p>
```

Code used for lazy is as below

```
text = '''
<p>
The very <em>first</em> task is to find the beginning of a paragraph.
</p>
<p>
Then you have to find the end of the paragraph
</p>
'''
#pattern=re.compile(r'\<p\>.*?\<\/p\>')
pattern=re.compile(r'<p>.*?</p>')
data1=pattern.match(text,re.MULTILINE)
print('data1:- ',data1,'\n')
```

I am getting None is both case as Actual Output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly, when using [`Pattern.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match), the second and third parameters are positional, not flags. The flags need to be specified to [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile). Secondly, you should be using [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) to make `.` match newline, not [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE). Finally - `match` insists that the match occurs at the beginning of the string (which in your case is a newline character), so it won't match. You might want to use [`Pattern.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search) instead. This will work for your sample input:

```
pattern=re.compile(r'<p>.*</p>', re.DOTALL)
data1=pattern.search(text)
print('data1:- ',data1.group(0),'\n')
```

Output:

```
data1:-  <p>
The very <em>first</em> task is to find the beginning of a paragraph.
</p>
<p>
Then you have to find the end of the paragraph
</p>
```

Single match:

```
pattern=re.compile(r'<p>.*?</p>', re.DOTALL)
data1=pattern.search(text)
print('data1:- ',data1.group(0),'\n')
```

Output:

```
data1:-  <p>
The very <em>first</em> task is to find the beginning of a paragraph.
</p>
```

Note also that `/`, `<` and `>` have no special meaning in regexes and don't need to be escaped. I've removed that in my code above.